# How to get the value of a group of dynamically created text boxes?

Tags: jquery

I have a group of dynamically created (while loop) text boxes / input fields driven from a database:

```
<input type='text' value='".htmlentities($page['special'], ENT_QUOTES)."' />
<input type='submit' class='button' value='Edit' />
<input type='submit' class='button' value='Delete' />
```

The number of fields may change upon the number of records in the database. At the right of every field there are two buttons: Edit and Delete. These two buttons (via Jquery `$get`) are used to update or delete the dB records.

My problem is that I don't know how to 'link' / bind the buttons to their field. I guess I have to use Jquery `index()` or `eq()` methods, but I don't know how nor if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of when the edit or delete button is clicked. You can find the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) text box traversing up the DOM.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var text_box = $(this).closest('input[type="text"]'); // get closest text box to the edit and delete button. 
});
```

This assumes your HTML structure is consistent to the one you posted above.

Comment: Thank you Interstellar_Coder, I tried your suggestion that appeared really elegant. I added an alert(text_box) to see the value retrieved but the message box displayed '[object Object]'.

Comment: Nicero, alert is old school. Use console.log( ) instead and it should show the object in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your inputs had a class, you could go through them like this:

```
$(".yourinputs").each({
    $(this).next().click(/*edit handler*/);
    $(this).next().next().click(/*delete handler*/);
});
```

Of course this assumes an HTML structure, so it might be wiser to give each of your inputs an ID, in a data field, like `<input data-id="21">`, and then in your edit button a real ID, like `edit-21`, and then you can fetch them realiably in the loop by doing `$("edit-" + $(this).data("id"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Give the input an `id='recordEdit_".$page['YourRecordSetID']."'` then you can use that id to get which recordset it links to